# Interpreting the Joint Distribution of $(X , X \mid Y)$

Tags: probability-distributions, intuition, conditional-probability

This is perhaps too much of a general question, but perhaps someone can give me some insight.

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are random variables. Now, I'm interested in the joint distribution
of $(X, X \mid Y)$.

I know that
$$P(X, X \mid Y) = P([X \mid Y] \mid X) P(X) = P(X \mid [X \mid Y])P(X \mid Y)
$$

Is it true then that $P(X, X \mid Y) = X P(X)$? What can one say about this joint distribution?
If necessary, assume that $X$ and $Y$ are continuous and that $P(X \mid Y) = f(x\mid y)$ is the conditional density function.